# Minimax won’t work with both 3x3 and 4x4 grids

Tags: java, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I made a minimax algorithm with alpha beta pruning for Tic Tac Toe. The A.I. works as expected for a 3x3 board but it does not work with a 4x4 board. I managed to fix the algorithm so that it picks the best move on a 4x4 board, but now it won’t work for a 3x3 and I am having trouble making the minimax method work with both 3x3 and 4x4 boards. I would like some help understanding why I have to change how the evaluate method is handled depending on board size. The problem seems to stem from when the score is evaluated from the evaluation method. When the score is evaluated with on a 3x3 it must run the evaluation method then return a 10 if the A.I. wins, a -10 if the opponent wins, or a 0 for a full board at the top of the minimax method. Then it continues with the rest of the algorithm if necessary. Here is the code:

```
    int score = evaluate(board);
    if (score == 10) {
        return score;
    }
    if (score == -10) {
        return score;
    }
    if (hasCellsLeft(board) == false) {
        return 0;
    }
```

For the algorithm to work properly on a 4x4 board the evaluation method is nested inside an if statement. If the depth equals 3 then the score is returned:

```
if (depth == 3) {
   return evaluate(board);
}
```

Here is the rest of the minimax method:

```
if (isMax) {
    int best = MIN;
    ArrayList<Integer> cells = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j=0; j<board.length; j++) {
        if (board[j].getToken() == Token.EMPTY) {
            cells.add(j);
         }
        }
        //cells is a list of empty cells in the board array
        for (int i=0; i<cells.size(); i++) {
            if (board[cells.get(i)].getToken() == Token.EMPTY) {
                board[cells.get(i)].setToken(playerToken);
                int val = alphaBeta(board, depth+1, nodeIndex*2+i,false, alpha, beta);
                best = Math.max(best, val);
                alpha = Math.max(alpha, best);
                board[cells.get(i)].resetMarker();
            }
            if (beta <= alpha) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return best;
    }
    else {
        int best = MAX;
        for (int i=0; i<board.length; i++) {
            if (board[i].getToken() == Token.EMPTY) {
                board[i].setToken(opponentToken);
                int val = alphaBeta(board,depth+1, nodeIndex*2+i, true, alpha, beta);
                best = Math.min(best, val);
                beta = Math.min(beta, best);
                board[i].resetMarker();
            }

            if (beta <= alpha) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return best;
    }
```

This method calls the minimax algorithm and retrieved the index for the best possible move:

```
public int findBestMove(Cell[] board) {
        int bestValue = -1000;
        int bestMove = -1;
        for (int i=0; i<board.length; i++) {
            if (board[i].getToken() == Token.EMPTY) {
                board[i].setToken(playerToken);
                int moveValue = alphaBeta(board, 0, 0, false, -1000, 1000);
                board[i].resetMarker();
                if (moveValue > bestValue) {
                    bestMove = i;
                    bestValue = moveValue;
                }
            }
        }
        return bestMove;
    }
```

This is the evaluation method:

```
public int evaluate(Cell[] board) {
    if (endStates.checkWinByRow(board, playerToken) || endStates.checkWinByColumn(board, playerToken) || endStates.checkWinByDiagonal(board, playerToken)) {
    return 10;
}
else if (endStates.checkWinByRow(board, opponentToken) || endStates.checkWinByColumn(board, opponentToken) || endStates.checkWinByDiagonal(board, opponentToken)) {
            return -10;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Method that returns true/false if there are unoccupied cells in board array:

```
public boolean hasCellsLeft(Cell[] board) {
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        if(board[i].getToken() == Token.EMPTY) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question? You put up requirements, and code, and some debug insights (which is btw: a good thing, most people dont do that) - but what now? What exactly do you expect us to do?

Comment: And unrelated: I would suggest to dramatically break up that min max method. Put each section into its own method - it is super hard to grasp a method that has so many lines and does so many different things!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am can’t figure out why it is behaving this way. I want it to work regardless of the board size. Instead I have to choose between them and can’t fathom why I need to rewrite how the algorithm handles the output of the evaluate method. I thought another pair of eyes would have better insight.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem but I won’t delete this in case it may help someone. I needed to change the number in the if statement from depth == 3 to 5.